# How do I increment a label by 1?

Tags: c#

I want to make it where when you click a picturebox it adds to the label incrementing by one, like you click picture box 2 times, the label now says "2".

Comment: Great idea. What have you tried so far to do so? (Have you created an OnClick handler for the PictureBox? Have you tried setting the Label.Text in that handler?) Please post the code you've written that tries to do so and isn't working.

Comment: Create a numeric variable and increase it every time you click, then convert `ToString` and set as the label text.

Answer (score 2):

```
lblMyLabel.Text = (int.Parse(lblMyLabel.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

I'm assuming winforms from the picturebox.  Parse the text into an int, then increase it, in your click event handler.